# Is it possible to force-write to an unrecognized SD card?

Tags: formatting, sd-card

I have an SD card that I am trying to salvage, but whenever I plug it in to my Macbook, it doesn't show up. I know the issue is not with the card reader because it can pick up several other cards just fine. Would it be possible to plug it in and then force a format operation pointed to the port where it supposedly is?

EDIT: When inserting the dysfunctioning SD card, neither Finder nor Disk Utilities detects it. My thought process is that the SD card was at one point totally blank, but then it was written to even when it was just plastic and silicon. Is it possible to have my computer send write operations to the port it is plugged in to with the hopes that it will eventually pick it up?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Flash media isn't "salvageable" in the same way old HDDs are. When it fails, it fails, end of story.

Comment: Ah, I see. This is all new to me, but I thought I'd give it a shot. Thanks @ChanganAuto

Comment: One thing you *can* try.. plug it into windows.. if that doesn't work, plug it into Linux.  It can't hurt.

Comment: While I do not entirely agree with ChanganAuto about "when it fails it fails, end of story" as I expect that it is possible to do forensic operations to recover data from them - a bit like with an SSD, once the drive is not detected by the PC its not worth trying to resuscitate as its cheaper (if your time has any value whatsoever) and, importantly,  way more reliable to just buy a new drive.